# Accepting internal position to leverage a new one

Tags: job-search, job-offer, relocation

Applied for an internal Software Engineer Level II job and successfully interviewed. However, the offer is super low... (69k in Denver)... and I've been working for two years with them.

Honestly, I'm kind of disgusted with how lowball they've been with me (as I've done a good job).

I need to accept the position because my lease is ending and I have to move... but I don't want to get stuck being underpaid in a rough job.

Can I accept the offer, and keep looking for jobs after moving up there?

I think if I was given a month or two I could probably find a job for 85k...

What do you think? Is  it bad to leave a new position quickly like that?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend accepting the offer, and looking for jobs after moving up there. Statistics can be used to point anything out, right or wrong. That being said, statistically about 20% of the worldwide workforce across market segments are "super passive" and NOT actively looking for work or other opportunities.

So therefore, 80% of the worlds workforce is somewhere on the spectrum from casually interested in looking at better opportunities to desperately seeking. I hope that helps put it into some perspective for you. Best of luck on your path.. T

Answer (score 2):

Check the policy of your company regarding transfers. This is important if they provide any bonus for taking the position, or if they help pay moving expenses. In these cases they may require you to pay back part or all of the bonus money or moving expenses if you leave before a year.

In some companies you may also be blocked from applying for other positions within the company after transferring to a new position.

Assuming there is nothing you signed that will limit your ability to quit, then there is nothing stopping you from looking for jobs outside the company.

I have not jumped to a position in order to move cities, but in cases where one project was ending I have made a jump to another project for coverage, while I continued to look outside the company.  If you do this the new project won't be happy, but they also know that anytime somebody joins their project it doesn't always end up working out.

Comment: There is no bonus. Straight 70k no help moving